# pgfplots multiple plots in one file

Tags: pgfplots, pgfplotstable

In pgfplots is it possible to have several plots in one datafile?

The goal is to add about 20 plots, which has different number of points and not the same x-value, to the same axis. (app. 350 points)

---

One posible solution is to have the plots in separate column, and then use loads of 'nan' because of the different x values:

```
    x  p1   p2  P3  ...
    1  3    nan nan ...
    2  nan  5   nan ...
    6  4    8   nan ...
    8  7    nan nan ...
    ...
```

I do not like this solution:o(

---

The [gnuplot](http://www.gnuplot.info/) solution is nice: the different plots are separated in the datafile by two newlines, and they are selected by 'index'. Does something similar exist in pgfplots? or any other solution?

Comment: What program / method do you use to generate the datafiles?

Comment: I've only ever tried this with one axis shared by all plots, so I'm not sure. Why do you want only one file though?

Comment: @MarkS.Everitt: I think Hans-Peter also wants the plots to be on the same axis, but they won't be defined at the same x-values.

Comment: The data are collected from different scientific articles, so there are no generating program. I would like them plotted on the same axis.

Comment: Oh, I see. Well that's easy then! Hang on...

Comment: See my updated entry. You can put all of your data into a single file with uneven columns. Even so, I'd recommend keeping them in separate files though if you can.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use gnuplot in the background by using `\addplot gnuplot [raw gnuplot] {<gnuplot commands>};`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{data.txt}
1 1
2 4
3 9
4 16
5 25


1 1
2.5 5
6 12
\end{filecontents*}


\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
\addplot gnuplot [raw gnuplot] {plot 'data.txt' index 0};
\addplot gnuplot [raw gnuplot] {plot 'data.txt' index 1};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: OK cool. I think that is the solution. I will try. The manual pretends that the gnuplot mode is only for function plotting:o)

Comment: Is it described somewhere exactly how much gnuplot is in the background. Who is in control of point/line type/color, ....

Comment: It's all PGFplots, all gnuplot does is generate a data file that is then read in PGFplots using `\addplot file ...`. From the PGFplots manual: "In contrast to `plot expression`, the `plot gnuplot` command employs the external program gnuplot
to compute coordinates. The resulting coordinates are written to a text file which will be plotted with
`plot file`".

Comment: Ok thank you. I knew that was the case with a function passed to gnuplot, but of cause its the same here.

Answer (score 12):

You can use the `\addplot` command multiple times on the same axes. The files that the different `\addplot`s take can be the same or different, and different columns etc.

```
\pgfplotsset{width=6cm,compat=newest}
\begin{axis}[
    scale only axis,
    xlabel={$\tau$ ($\mu$s)},
    ylabel={P(bitflip)},
    ymin=0,
    ymax=1,
    xmin=0,
    xmax=125.66,
]
\addplot[color=red]
    table[x=time,y=fidelity] {data1.txt};
\addplot[color=black]
    table[x=time,y=fidelity] {data1.txt};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

It's not so clear here, but I used data from two sample files to plot this

[image]

The data files here are indexed by column headers, but you can also do this by number. One of the files begins with the following lines:

```
time    fidelity
0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00
2.02874597e-01  9.75413405e-05
5.19896845e-01  4.76482130e-04
8.36998426e-01  7.26895359e-04
1.15410184e+00  7.52986468e-04
1.47115744e+00  8.85559658e-04
```

You can put multiple columns in one file, and gaps (just whitespace) are tolerated. In the following plot one data file is used with four columns, and there are clear gaps in the time and amplitude entries for the red plot.

[image]

```
\pgfplotsset{width=6cm,compat=newest}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    scale only axis,
    xlabel={$\tau$ (ns)},
    ylabel={Negativity},
    ymin=-1,
    ymax=1,
    xmin=0,
    xmax=6.3,
    legend style={font=\small,at={(0.5,0.96)},anchor=north,style={nodes={right}}},
]
\addplot[color=black]
    table[x index=0,y index=1] {data.txt};
\addplot[color=red]
    table[x index=2,y index=3] {data.txt};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Note that there are no column headers this time (just for variety). Gaps look like

```
2.28479466e+00  7.55749574e-01  -6.54860734e-01 2.28479466e+00  
2.34826118e+00  7.12694171e-01  -7.01474888e-01 2.34826118e+00  
2.41172769e+00  6.66769001e-01  -7.45264450e-01 2.41172769e+00  
2.47519421e+00  6.18158986e-01      
2.53866073e+00  5.67059864e-01      
2.60212725e+00  5.13677392e-01      
2.66559377e+00  4.58226522e-01      
2.72906028e+00  4.00930535e-01      
2.79252680e+00  3.42020143e-01      
2.85599332e+00  2.81732557e-01      
2.91945984e+00  2.20310533e-01      
2.98292636e+00  1.58001396e-01      
3.04639288e+00  9.50560433e-02      
3.10985939e+00  3.17279335e-02      
3.17332591e+00  -3.17279335e-02     
3.23679243e+00  -9.50560433e-02     
3.30025895e+00  -1.58001396e-01     
3.36372547e+00  -2.20310533e-01     
3.42719199e+00  -2.81732557e-01     
3.49065850e+00  -3.42020143e-01     
3.55412502e+00  -4.00930535e-01     
3.61759154e+00  -4.58226522e-01 -8.88835449e-01 3.61759154e+00  
3.68105806e+00  -5.13677392e-01 -8.57983413e-01 3.68105806e+00  
3.74452458e+00  -5.67059864e-01 -8.23676581e-01 3.74452458e+00  
3.80799110e+00  -6.18158986e-01 -7.86053095e-01 3.80799110e+00
```

It should also be fine to have uneven columns, provided the number of tabs or commas is correct.

Comment: Yes - that was my idea, but it involves loads of loads of 'nan' because of the different x-values. -or maybe I do not understand.

Comment: But wouldn't this solution require one datafile per plot? If I understand correctly, Hans-Peter wants to be able to generate several different plots (with different number of data points and different sampling intervals) from a single `data.csv` file.

Comment: Nope. See my update. pgfplots doesn't care about missed columns, so long as the number of tabs or commas is correct. At least that's what my basic trials showed. Not sure if it'll stand up to too much abuse. This is similarly true of uneven column lengths.

Comment: Oh yeah, okay, but the problem that you have to provide the right number of somethings, be they `nan` or tabs or commas, would remain with this approach.

Comment: @Jake: Then the answer is simple. Place the columns in descending order of length, or script a solution to add in the extra tabs or columns. That should not be difficult.

Comment: You are right 'nan' is not necessary. In my case I have (cat HSI.dat |cut -sf 1|sort -n|uniq|wc -l) 98 different x-values, and 20 plots giving a table of 1960 entries for only 350 points... and a lot of work to interleave my datafile.

Comment: This way interleaving should not be necessary, as long as you're happy to provide `x` and `y` axes every time. i.e. assuming that you're not using one axis with integers and reusing some values for multiple plots (seems unlikely).

Comment: @MarkS.Everitt: Yeah, or you could just collect all the series in an Excel or OpenOffice spreadsheet and save it as a `csv`, which will take care of the right number of field separators. Thinking about it, I guess your approach is preferable to the `\addplot gnuplot` method because of the ability to use column names instead of just indexes.

Comment: that would give a table of 350*20=7000 entries for only 350 points:o)

Comment: @Hans-PeterE.Kristiansen: You might want to think of converting your datafile to a file like Mark suggests, it'll make the maintenance of the datafile a lot easier ("What was the 16th block of data again?").

Comment: True pgplots(or gnuplot) does not know what index x is, but I have a comment in the datafile itself.

Comment: Not necessary. See my second example. You can index by column (starting with zero).

Comment: @MarkS.Everitt: The table solution without nan does not work, because any number of tabs will only be read as one.

Comment: So ragged bottom doesn't work? How about with columns in order of descending size? Commas?

Answer (score 2):

The other answers weren't *immediately* clear to me. After struggling for a bit, I found that it's very easy to draw multiple lines from the same file.

You can simply put **white lines** in your data file and you're done:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{filecontents,pgfplots}

\begin{filecontents}{test.dat}
x   y
1   0.5
2   0.5
2   1
1   1
1   0.5

1   2.5
2   2.5
2   3
1   3
1   2.5
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]
\begin{axis}
[
    axis lines=left, axis line style={->},
    xmin=0,xmax=5,
    ymin=0,ymax=5
]
\addplot [] table [x=x, y=y] {test.dat};    % Plot all shapes in data file
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Which gives two separately drawn lines:

[image: Two lines in one graph]

Hope this speeds up someone's search for an answer ;)

Comment: Of course that works, but it one major downside: You cannot change the style of the "second" plot. If there is an equal number of points before the blank line(s) one can use <http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/309014/pgfplots-create-multiple-plots-from-one-table-rows-0-3-4-7/337082#337082> and is able to change the style of the different plots.

Comment: The problem here is that you are not really adding multiple plots(you only have one `\addplot`), so you lose all the features. @Jake's solution have double blank lines, and `\addplot gnuplot [raw gnuplot]`. -so your new answer will not speed up anyones search, as the problem was already solved.